# pf - redirect rule does not work

Tags: pf

I'm using pf on FreeBSD 9.
sshd is up and listening on loopback only (127.0.0.1).

Trying to use redirect rule to allow network hosts to connect via ssh.

```
set block-policy drop
set skip on lo0
scrub in

no rdr on lo0 all
rdr on fxp0 inet proto tcp from any to (fxp0) port = ssh -> 127.0.0.1

block drop in log quick on ! lo inet from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
block drop log on fxp0 all
pass in quick on fxp0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port ssh
pass out quick on fxp0 all keep state
```

This does not work for some reason and I see no related messages in pflog.

Tried also with `rdr pass` with same result.

I see this status from `pfctl -ss`:

```
all tcp 127.0.0.1:22 (192.168.0.40:22) <- 192.168.0.252:65105   CLOSED:SYN_SENT
```

When I turn logging for rdr, I see this:

```
rdr in on fxp0: 192.168.0.252.65105 > 127.0.0.1.22: Flags [S], seq 1927917349, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 3,sackOK,TS[|tcp]>
```

What is wrong with my setup?

How to get more log output?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's three years old and lacks sufficient information to find an answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your sshd listening addresses?

```
$ netstat -a | grep ssh
tcp4       0      0 *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

The first ***** means that sshd is listening on every local addresses on the machine including 127.0.0.1.

> SSHD_CONFIG(5)
>
> ```
>  ListenAddress
>          Specifies the local addresses sshd(8) should listen on.  The fol-
>          lowing forms may be used:
>
>                ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr|IPv6_addr
>                ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr:port
>                ListenAddress [host|IPv6_addr]:port
>
>          If port is not specified, sshd will listen on the address and all
>          prior Port options specified.  The default is to listen on all
>          local addresses.  Multiple ListenAddress options are permitted.
>          Additionally, any Port options must precede this option for non-
>          port qualified addresses.
> ```

If sshd is not listening on address 127.0.0.1, it is shown as CLOSED:SYN_SENT in `pfctl -ss` output.

`netstat` output after making sshd listen on 192.168.10.114 only.

```
$ netstat -a | grep ssh
tcp4       0      0 192.168.10.114.ssh     *.*                    LISTEN
```

While trying to ssh to this machine, `pfctl -ss` output is like below.

```
$ pfctl -ss
all tcp 127.0.0.1:22 (192.168.10.114:22) <- 192.168.10.107:50701       CLOSED:SYN_SENT
```

ssh connection is redirected to 127.0.0.1 by rdr rule - SYN packet is sent to 127.0.0.1:tcp/22 (SYN_SENT)

However, 127.0.0.1:tcp/22 is not open, it is shown as CLOSED.

Comment: or try sockstat to display listening sockets; ~]sockstat -4l | grep ssh